# What is the right pattern of the answers for the questions of the specific kind?

Tags: tag-questions

Recently, I was asked at the forum by one of the participants:

> "A.D., you are not Swedish?"
>
> I answered "**Yes**, I'm not."

But now I think I should have answered "**No**, I'm not."

Which is right? The first or the second variant? Or are both wrong?

Comment: The *question* is incorrectly posed. It should be *A.D., **are/have you** [not] **finished**?* Note that optional ***not*** would normally only be included if the speaker *believes* that you haven't finished yet. If he's *right* about that, the natural response is *No I'm not / No, I haven't.* If he''s *wrong*, you'd be more likely to set him straight by saying ***Actually**, I have finished* (it doesn't really make sense to include the word ***Yes*** in a reply which contradicts the implication of a question).

Comment: I'm sorry, It should be `finnish` ( etnicity ) instead of `finish.`

Comment: oic. I've changed ***Finnish*** to ***Swedish*** to prevent others from making the same mistake. I probably wouldn't have mis-read it if the capitalisation correction had been made earlier, but the mere fact that someone else had to do this for you (*after* you repeated the error in your above comment) suggests it's an unwanted distraction. Note that I speak ***British English***, not ***british english*** (I'm impressed - my built-in Google Chrome spell-checker has just objected to that second version purely because of the lack of capitalisation! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should have said, "No, I'm not."

Your initial logic is valid but the normal idiomatic response to questions like that is to answer "No, I'm not X."

Hopwever - if the questioner is wanting you NOT to be finished, and therefore you really want to affirm exactly what he is saying with a positive phrase, you should say, "Right, I'm not finished." or "You're right, I'm not finished."

Comment: I'm sorry, It should be `finnish` ( etnicity ) instead of `finish.`

Answer (score 2):

The logic to answering such questions is as follows:

- *Yes, I am* - if you are.
- *No, I am not* - if you aren't.

You can't self-contradict and say **Yes, I am not** or **No, I am**.

But you can state the truth by saying things like **You are right, I am not**.

Here are a few examples:

- Are you Finnish?
- Yes, I am.

---

- Are you not John?
- No, I am not.

---

- Are you not a teacher?
- Yes, I am.

---

- Are you German?
- No, I am not.